# replacing string value in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am having a string like below:

```
my $testing = 'EmailId=learner.here@stackoverflow.com&passWord=mypassword123';
```

in my Perl code all I want to do is take this value as input and replace the value of passWord with something like `****3` (where `3` is the last character of the actual password);
that is final output is:

```
"EmailId=learner.here@stackoverflow.com&passWord=****3"
```

I am able to produce the output like above in Perl using following approach:

```
my $testing = 'EmailId=learner.here@stackoverflow.com&passWord=mypassword123';
my ( $val, $val1) = split( 'passWord=', $testing );
my $string =  $with_this . substr($val1,length($val1) - 1);
print "\n" . $val . 'passWord=' . $string . "\n";
```

Can someone help me understand if this is right approach or how can this be made better.
It works fine but I still there should be some easy way to do this using regular expression or something else.

1. Made code better or do it in less complicated way
2. Handle condition if actual value did not even exit
3. Or any other suggestions

I am new bee to programming, so did my research and came up with solution I mentioned above.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the original value with the correct number of asterisks, except for the last character:

```
$testing =~ s/passWord=([^&]+)/'passWord=' . ('*' x (length($1) - 1)) . substr($1, -1)/e;
```

Comment: this works perfectly fine, but i can see from comments to my question that in case if password is not the last character of the line what happens in those case and so on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how do you handle case like this :       my $testing = 'EmailId=learner.here@stackoverflow.com&passWord=mypassword123,someOtherId=its Value';

Comment: It's kind of strange to have different delimiters throughout the same string, but just change `[^&]` to `[^,]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$testing =~ s/\bpassWord=\K.*(?=.)/****/s;
```

If the password isn't always found at the end of the string, some adjustment will be needed. For example, the following handles the case where the password can be ended by `,`.

```
$testing =~ s/[&,]passWord=\K[^,]*(?=[^,])/****/s;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity how do you handle case like this :       my $testing = 'EmailId=learner.here@stackoverflow.com&passWord=mypassword123,someOtherId=its Value';